# What on earth is an Alpha Model in the quantative investment process?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, modern-portfolio-theory, quants, active-investing

I am confused with the useage of the concept "**Alpha Model**" in quantative investment. According to Qian, Hua & Sorensen (2007), the first thing in the toolbox of quantative investment process is "an alpha model that forecasts excess return of stocks"(Page 5). And on page 81, the author mentioned that "an important component of any successful investment strategy is forecasting expected returns using alpha models".

So, what should an alpha model do? Predict **excess return** or predict **expected return**? Given the word "alpha" in the term "alpha model", shouldn't it predict the "**alpha**"(i.e., the risk-adjusted return, e.g., Jensen's Alpha) for each stock so that we can select stocks with high alphas to construct portfolio?

In addition, a common method to evaluate an "**alpha factor**" is to calculate the "**information coefficient**", which is usually defined as "the correlation between the **forecasts** and the eventual returns"(Grinold & Kahn, 2000; Qian, Hua & Sorensen, 2007). But an "alpha factor" itself is just a "number" calculated for each stock(see [this post](https://www.quantopian.com/posts/a-professional-quant-equity-workflow)), not a return forecast, and some people seem to just use the correlation between the raw alpha factor values and stock returns as the "information coefficient". So I wonder which is right for the calculation of information coefficient. If we calculate it as "the correlation between the forecasts and the eventual returns", then how to get the "forecasts" given the raw alpha factor values?

Reference

Grinold & Kahn, 2000, Active Portfolio Management: A Quantitative Approach for Producing Superior Returns and Controlling Risk

Qian, Hua & Sorensen, 2007, Quantitative Equity Portfolio Management: Modern Techniques and Applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Alpha Model:

First and foremost is an alpha model that forecasts excess return of stocks in Investment process. If return    distribution is characterized by the expected return and the standard deviation, it is often the    expected return that determines whether we buy or sell, overweight or underweight, and the  standard deviation that determines the size of the portfolio allocations. It is easier to find  random factors that represent non-compensated market risk than to find alpha factors that   represents incremental rewards. The alpha model is often proprietary and highly guarded,    reflecting creativity as well as superior systems. It is the most important differentiator within the   investment firm.

Comment: Year,  this is from Qian (2007) on page 5. But on page 81, the author mentioned "expected return".      That's what I'm confused with. And I also want to konw whether an alpha model should predict the risk adjusted return (the so-called "alpha" in asset pricing theory). After all, there's a word "alpha" in the term "alpha model".

Comment: Please refer to page no. 82 last paragraph; For long-only Portfolios managed against a benchmark, alpha is the portfolio excess return over the benchmark; For Long-Short market neutral portfolio, alpha is the excess return over cash. Please do not get confuse with "Expected return" and "Excess Return", For Expected Return, we have "CAPM" in place.

Comment: Thanks! So, the goal of an alpha model is to predict the excess return. But why does the author call the excess return "alpha"? As far as I know, excess return is stock/portfolio return minus benchmark return (Strictly speaking, this is active return, because in asset pricing theory, excess return is stock return minus risk-free return. But let's just call it excess return here), and alpha is "stock return minus beta times market prerium return", i.e., R-beta * E(Rm-Rf). It is very confusing. Maybe it is just a difference between acdemic research and practice usage?

Comment: I can understand it's confusing at initial stage. I am working on Projects where we are going to implement all the modles discussed in Qian, Hua & Sorensen book, Actually Grinold & Kahn, 2000; Qian, Hua & Sorensen, 2007 both books go hand in hand. If you are satisfied with the above answer pls vote up and close the question. Thanks.

Comment: In addition, if an alpha model only predicts excess return (relative to the benchmark), how can we get "abnormal return" using this model? For example, we can use "market beta" as "alpha factor". According to CAPM, high beta means high excess return. Then we choose those stocks with highest beta to construct our portfolio in our quantative strategy and gain an "excess return". However, this "excess return" is obtained just because we bear more systematic risk! We don't have any "active management skill". If so, I can't see the usefulness of an alpha model.

Comment: Alpha is also often referred to as “excess return” or “abnormal rate of return,” which refers to the idea that markets are efficient, and so there is no way to systematically earn returns that exceed the broad market as a whole. Please note CAPM is a theory and like any theory in social science it is based on assumptions that are not quite accurate. The idea behind the CAPM help the active manager's to avoid the risk of market timings and to focus research on residual returns that have a consensus expectations of zero. To understand the use of Alpha model pls read my answer again. Thanks.

Comment: Hi: I wouldn't bother with the term "excess return" because it assumes that we know the expected return and, in practice, you usually don't. If you can forecast the actual return, you should  be pretty happy with that and call it whatever you want !!!!! Excess return is an academic-CAPM type term so not necessary for forecasting returns.

Comment: Let's say alpha is excess return, i.e. the stock return minus benchmark return, and an alpha model predicts excess return. What next? We need to use the prediction of this alpha model to select stocks, right? And usualy we select those stocks with high forecasting excess returns, right? Then we construct portfolio, implement our strategy, et, al. Finally, this portfolio outperforms the benchmark, and we say our startegy gains excess return relative to the choosen benchmark, right? .......

Comment: ......But, it's very likely we obtained excess terturn just because we selected stocks with high betas. If we use CAPM or Fama-French 3 Factor Model to do performance attribution analysis, we may find we didn't obtain any residual return. This is what I am concerned about.

Comment: Answer to What's next is ; By using Alpha models you got the excess returns, but based on excess returns we can't invest in market and expect profits, we need to model the risk as well which is associated with the stocks we choose for our investment portfolio. So your next step is  using Risk models to eliminate stock's which has high risk and does not fit into Portfolio objective.

Comment: @Atul Agarwal: Theoretically, your comments are all well stated and true. But, do you really believe in the correctness of  risk models ? Using a risk model is adding another level of uncertainty to the already present uncertainty in the forecast. So, personally, I would stay away from risk models, particularly if they were vendor based.

Comment: @Mark Leeds; Yes I believe in Risk Models. I prefer to concentrate on multiple factors instead of set of stocks. Because we all know stock's change but factors does not. The situation is much simpler when we focus on the smaller number of factors and allow the stocks to change their exposures to those factors.

Comment: @Godel I would like to know what process are you following to achieve the Objective of Portfolio. Will you be able to share steps with examples.

Comment: @AtulAgarawal  Actually, I previously thought the goal of an alpha model was to predict stocks' alphas (in the sense of Jensen's alpha, i.e., risk-adjusted return. Grinold & Kahn also use it with this meanning). Basically, I want to buy stocks with positive "alphas", and when I use Index Futures to hedge the systematic market risk (i.e., the beta part of the total return), the strategy can still obtain the "alpha" return. That's why I'm confused about what an alpha model should predict. If it just predict excess return, I can't use it to choose stocks with high alphas (risk-adjusted return).

Comment: @Atul Agarwal: I agree, assuming the risk model works. Do you build your own or use an off the shelf kind ?

Comment: @markleeds As to risk model, maybe we can implement Barra Multifactor Risk Model, following the steps described in the handbook of USE4 Model. I don't know whether this is  a good choice or not.

Comment: @Godel: Hi:  I used to use barra risk models in the previous century but haven't kept up with them since. I don't know if they are still popular but, if you're going to use an off the shelf risk model, I would imagine that's the way to go. There are other vendors also but Barra models were definitely respected back in those days.

Comment: @Godel; Barra models are still in use and treated as Benchmark for comparisons with other risk models in top institutions.

Comment: @AtulAgarawal  Hi, would you give me some suggestions about how to build a strategy just like what I have described in comments? I don't know whether there is a standard procedure to build this kind of strategies.

Comment: @Godel: You can look after "Extension Equity Strategy" if you are looking a cross between long only Mutual fund and Hedge fund. If you want long-short strategy then you can look after 130/30 as well.